# Wireless LAN dropped out--IS IT WORN OUT?

Tags: networking, wireless

I've been synching the full bitcoin blockchain from scratch and my puter has been running day and night for the past week or so to catch up with 9 years and 18 weeks of blocks.

I got to within 15 weeks or 90.1% of complete synchronization (168 GB of download) when it appears my wireless card has given up the ghost.

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 and this was the output of `ifconfig` a couple of weeks ago:

```
snerx@snerx:~$ ifconfig
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:57:a5:d6:e5:cb  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3705 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3705 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:283781 (283.7 KB)  TX bytes:283781 (283.7 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:6d:c7:c8:95:ff  
          inet addr:192.168.1.14  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6502:ea3a:72:87d7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:19978 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:6440
          TX packets:15558 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:20485773 (20.4 MB)  TX bytes:2341162 (2.3 MB)
          Interrupt:19
```

This is the output after the dropout:

```
snerx@snerx:~$ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3796  bytes 229996 (229.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3796  bytes 229996 (229.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

snerx@snerx:~$ ifconfig enp2s0
enp2s0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
snerx@snerx:~$ ifconfig wlp3s0
wlp3s0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
snerx@snerx:~$
```

Am I right in thinking the network card is stuffed and that it needs to be replaced? I'm running an HP 20-e022a.

---

On the recommendation of @chili555 I've run the wireless-info script written by Wild Man and Krytarik. Here is the output:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 23 May 2018 10:53 AEST +1000

Booted last: 23 May 2018 00:00 AEST +1000

Script from: 10 Jan 2018 20:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.13.0-43-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 16 12:18:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash

##### desktop ###########################

/usr/share/xsessions/plasma

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:2b5a]

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
    Kernel modules: wl

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp.
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05c8:0229 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0461:4d0f Primax Electronics, Ltd HP Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:07b6 Microsoft Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 25324  bytes 1522196 (1.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 25324  bytes 1522196 (1.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       810     1  0 08:16 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=false

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Puxtor-primary]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Puxtor-primary | type=wifi | permissions=user:snerx:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Puxtor-primary
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/OPTUSVD388A730 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=OPTUSVD388A730 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=OPTUSVD388A730
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/holodeck]] (600 root)
[connection] id=holodeck | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=holodeck
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/holodeck-bb8a128e-2899-48ec-a7b6-053ddd8e69c8]] (600 root)
[connection] id=holodeck | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=holodeck
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/OPTUSVD388A730]] (600 root)
[connection] id=OPTUSVD388A730 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=OPTUSVD388A730
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/iiNetB29095]] (600 root)
[connection] id=iiNetB29095 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=iiNetB29095
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/WiFi-4VCH]] (600 root)
[connection] id=WiFi-4VCH | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=WiFi-4VCH
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TPG-*******]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TPG-******* | type=wifi | permissions=user:snerx:;
[wifi] bssid=<MAC address> | mac-address=60:6D:C7:C8:95:FF | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=TPG-*******
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=ignore

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Fon WiFi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Fon WiFi | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Fon WiFi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Telstra Air]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Telstra Air | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Telstra Air
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Telstra7301E3]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Telstra7301E3 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Telstra7301E3
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

nl80211 not found.

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/network_drivers.conf]
install rt2800usb /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install rt2800usb $CMDLINE_OPTS; /bin/echo "2001 3c25" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/new_id

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

That doesn't make too much sense to me but wiser heads may be able to tell me what may be the problem...

---

I ran the following command and got nothing really:

```
snerx@snerx:~/Desktop/wireless-info$ sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl  
[sudo] password for snerx:  
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg) 
snerx@snerx:~/Desktop/wireless-info$
```

---

And I'll add this for good measure:

```
snerx@snerx:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:81300000-81300fff memory:a0000000-a0003fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:81200000-81207fff
snerx@snerx:~$
```

---

And this:

```
snerx@snerx:~$ lspci -nn | grep -i network
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
snerx@snerx:~$
```

---

I think this might be relevant:

```
snerx@snerx:~$ sudo iw reg get
n180211 not found.
snerx@snerx:~$
```

Comment: I doubt that it is stuffed. Let's have a look at the full diagnostics: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks @chili555. I copied the wireless-info script onto a USB and ran it on my Ubuntu machine and the output is copied above.

Comment: Please run: `sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl` and edit your question to add the result.

Comment: Wow! You have no drivers *at all* for either ethernet or wireless. If you interrupt the boot process and get to the GRUB menu, can you boot into an earlier kernel version than 4.13.0-43 and does everything work?

Comment: Well I be damned if that didn't work! I fired up Ubuntu with kernel version 4.13.0-41-generic and Wifi is up and running again. Thanks for your help Chili555.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you reinstall the faulty 4.13.0-43 kernel and associated parts. From the terminal:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-4.13.0-43-generic
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-4.13.0-43-generic
```

Reboot.

**EDIT**: Next, reinstall the driver. While booted into x.41 where you have internet access, open a terminal and do:

```
cd ~/Desktop
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

Now reboot into x.43 and do:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```

Any errors? If not, load the driver:

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

Any improvement?

---

*ThorF wrote 05/30/2018 at 6:04 PM*

Done a reinstall but got the error message you mentioned below (see output)

```
snerx@snerx:~/Desktop$ sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.d
eb  
[sudo] password for snerx:  
(Reading database ... 345297 files and directories currently installed.) 
Preparing to unpack bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb ... 
Removing all DKMS Modules 
Done. 
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3) over (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubunt
u3) ... 
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3) ... 
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files... 
Building for 4.13.0-43-generic 
Building for architecture x86_64 
Building initial module for 4.13.0-43-generic 
Done. 

wl: 
Running module version sanity check. 
- Original module 
  - No original module exists within this kernel 
- Installation 
  - Installing to /lib/modules/4.13.0-43-generic/updates/dkms/ 

depmod... 

DKMS: install completed. 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see
dmesg) 
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated) 
Processing triggers for shim-signed (1.33.1~17.10.1+13-0ubuntu2) ... 
Secure Boot not enabled on this system. 
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.125ubuntu12.1) ... 
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-43-generic
snerx@snerx:~/Desktop$
```

Comment: I reinstalled the 0.43 kernel as per these instructions (with two dashes in --reinstall) but the "invisible" wifi problem persisted. Went back and tried recovery mode but this too made no difference. I'm back to kernel version 0.41 again. Is this a systemic issue with version 0.43?

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: Still no improvement with the bcmwl-kernel-source install (see outputs above). Bit of a mystery this really...

Comment: Did the reinstall of *bcmwl-kernel-source* go without errors or warnings? Is the response still: "ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Unknown symbol in module"?

Comment: I posted the output fro the reinstall but it's been edited out it seems. Thought I'd copied and pasted it to a word document but can't seem to find it. From memory there were no error messages with the second reinstall. Perhaps I should try again. Am running kernel 0-41 at the moment.

Comment: When I reinstalled the bcmwl patch on the 0-43 kernel the wifi dropped out on kernel 0-41. But then it's rescued by reinstalling the patch again. I've posted the output from that install.

Comment: I don't understand. There is no error in what you've edited above. If you have results to show me, paste them here and give me the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I've pasted the installation output from bmcwl patch on the 0-41 kernel as well as an updated wireless-info report.   https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PPXTcd85Xj/

Comment: I've upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel version 4.15.0-20 and wifi connection is working straight out of the box. That solved the problem of no connectivity with kernel version 4.13.0-43.